# can aws system manager parameter store be exposed to outside aws space (as a REST api)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

can aws system manager parameter store be exposed to outside aws space (as a REST api)?
is there a built-in mechanism available in aws eco system? Trying to understand whether the configuration stored in parameter store can be exposed to outside aws (accessible via internet)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing out-of-the-box. However, you can create an `API Gateway endpoint` and execute a `lambda function` and read the `SSM parameter` value and return it.